# Json Zero considered as NSNumber and greater as NSstring

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring, nsnumber

When the value of a JSON entry is zero Xcode considers it an `NSNumber`, and when it is greater as an `NSString`.
The problem is when using a `if` to check the value, the app crashes in some cases.
I would like to check if the JSON value is 0, how should I resolve this?

JSON:

```
(
    {
    likesCount = 0; // NSNumber
    }
)
```

---

```
(
    {
    likesCount = 1; // NSString
    }
)
```

Comment: post your crash report and post the code where you check the values

Comment: What are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: When you say Xcode considers it an `NSNumber`, do yo actually mean that `NSJSONSerialization` considers it this?

Comment: Note that you're not posting the JSON, you're posting the NSLog dump of a dictionary.  In the original JSON a string will be surrounded by quotes, while a number will be "bare".  It would be poor practice for your JSON supplier to send different data types for the same key, but that's between you and the supplier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `integerValue` property, which exists on both `NSNumber` and `NSString`.